# Getting #<FbGraph::InvalidRequest: OAuthException :: Unknown path components:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-opengraph, fb-graph

I'm using the FbGraph gem with Rails. Every time I try to publish an action, I get this error:

```
[OpenGraph] Publishing publish #<GroupComment> (valid user token)
[OpenGraph] #<FbGraph::InvalidRequest: OAuthException :: Unknown path components: /gaymerx:publish>
OAuthException :: Unknown path components: /gaymerx:publish
```

Custom log format, but the error is as printed. gaymerx is our app's namespace, and we've created the publish action (though we have to post some 'publish' actions to fb before we can submit it). Verified that the user token is valid, and has open graph permissions.

Here's the calling code:

```
me = FbGraph::User.me(@token)
action = me.og_action!("gaymerx:#{action}", :custom_object => "http://www.gaymerconnect.com/action")
```

Any idea what could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing part of the request path

You have `/gaymerx:publish` but if your app namespace is `gaymerz` and your action is `publish` you should be posting to `/me/gaymerx:publish` or `/<USER ID HERE>/gaymerx:publish`

Comment: Nope - "FbGraph::InvalidRequest: OAuthException :: Unknown path components: /me/gaymerx:like"

Comment: What does the sample code in the app settings interface (open graph section) tell you to do? the format is definitely `/me/<namespace>:<action type>`